# How to use the .NET ZipArchive and ZipArchiveEntry classes to extract a file with a PASSWORD

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, c#-ziparchive

I am extracting the contents of a zip file with the following code:

```
using(ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
    {
        entry.ExtractToFile("extract.txt");
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for those zip files which are not password protected, however, I need it to also work for those passwords which are password protected.

I have seen other samples which can achieve what I want using other classes or other code but I find this way to be very clean and I hope that there is a property where I can set the password (it shouldn't need to be any more difficult than that).

Comment: I don't believe these classes support password protected zip files.

Comment: Is switching to [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) a valid option?  They support it.

Comment: Thanks Oded, I thought as much but I also thought such a basic feature would be supported. Not to worry, will use an alternative method.

Comment: DotNetZip - I did come across that just now when searching and although it seems a valid option it seems like something I have to pay for, plus I am not keen on using assemblies not from the .NET framework if I can help it.  Will check it out and thanks for your comment.

Comment: Bobson, I retract my statement.  It is actually free!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oded said, the built-in classes don't support passwords.  You should try an external library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).  It's free, powerful, and supports just about everything you'd need.

In this case, the example for you is:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
  {
    ZipEntry e = zip["TaxInformation-2008.xls"];
    e.ExtractWithPassword(BaseDirectory, Password);
  }
```

Comment: Bobson, I tried to use ZipFile.Read on a memory stream, a memory stream which previously was reading fine using the ZipArchive class. Error tells me it cannot be read as a ZipFile, although the overloads support a stream.  Any idea why or how I should be doing it? Thanks

Comment: @Shumii - Honestly, I don't.  As far as I know, it ought to work just fine if you pass it a stream.  Is it erroring on the `Read` line or the `ExtractWithPassword` line?

Comment: @Shumii - No idea.  The only two things I can think of are that you'll need to explicitly specify the encoding, or that it can't handle a stream for an encrypted zip.  There's nothing indicating that in the documentation, though, and I've never tried it myself.

Comment: I got it mate - I hadn't set the Position property on the MemoryStream to 0, although I didn't find that obvious.  Probably just my lack of understanding.

Comment: I would have never have thought of that.