# How can i create a zip file with a password in windows store 8.1 apps c#

Tags: c#, windows, zip, archive

I looked for api to anything could create a zip file with password for windows store 8.1 apps but finally nothing works!
did anyone can help please

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this resolve all the problem
 www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZipforWindows8.1/

Comment: Sadly this does not pass the certification Kit evalutation

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899325/how-to-use-the-net-ziparchive-and-ziparchiveentry-classes-to-extract-a-file-wit) with the .NET built in classes.

You can follow the suggestion there, and use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) . Since it comes with its source code, you can include it in your project and not depend on an external DLL, which may be a problem with a Windows Store App.

Comment: Are you suggesting that recompile DotNetZip with windows 8.1 project ?

Comment: Yes, you should try that.

Comment: the problem is the solution need mscorlib  assembly
in windows app 8.1 this mscorlib  don't exist ;(